# Truncate string on certain word occurence

Tags: ruby

How do I truncate a string on a certain word occurence?

E.g., I got the string:

```
a = "Is your question about programming? <--truncate--> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."
```

I want to output only **"Is your question about programming?"**

Comment: So, you want to truncate string on the word "programming?"?

Comment: no, "<--truncate-->" is the "word" that should truncate everything after it and itself as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a regex that matches the keyword and everything after that until the end of the string, then apply a `sub` replacement to the string that replaces the match with nothing:

```
string = "Is your question about programming? <--truncate-->\nWe prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."

keyword = '<--truncate-->'
regex = /#{Regexp.escape keyword}.*\z/m

string.sub(regex, '')
#=> "Is your question about programming? "
```

I ensured that it works with multi-line strings as well. You probably want to tack on a `.strip` at the end to remove leading and trailing whitespace:

```
string.sub(regex, '').strip
#=> "Is your question about programming?"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.split('<--truncate-->').first.strip
```

Or split with regexp

```
a.split(/\s*<--truncate-->/).first
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there seems to be at most one separator (like `<!--more-->` in WordPress), I'd use [`String#partition`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/String.html#method-i-partition):

```
a = "Is your question about programming? <--truncate--> We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed." 

excerpt, separator, more = a.partition('<--truncate-->')

excerpt    #=> "Is your question about programming? "
separator  #=> "<--truncate-->"
more       #=> " We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed."
```

Answer (score -1):

You can slice a string with a range.  Index the truncate to indicate the end of your slice.

```
a[0...a.index("<--truncate-->")]
# => "Is your question about programming?"
```

And you can accomplish the same thing with regex:

```
a.match(/(.*)<--truncate-->/).captures.first
# => "Is your question about programming?"
```